# Convert raw data into a structured table

Tags: java, hex, arrays, endianness, hexdump

I have extracted a raw data file from a magnetic tape using the dd command

Afterwards, I managed to read the extracted data with Bless HexEditor and I found out that at offset 0x200000 there is a table stored.

I would like to extract this data and import it in an Excel or CSV file:

This is an example of the data extracted in hexadecimal format and its representation in unsigned int little endian:

```
//Hex Not.    //Little-Endian unsigned int 32
10 00 00 00   // 84       (Ref Number)  
54 00 00 00   // 70185301 (Ref Number)
55 F1 2E 04   // 20070306 (Date)
A2 3F 32 01   // 15144184 (Time)
F8 14 E7 00   // 20070306 (Date)
A2 3F 32 01   // 15491037 (Time)
DD 5F EC 00   // 1
01 00 00 00   // 1
01 00 00 00   // 4486656
00 76 44 00   // 492
EC 01 00 00   // 1
01 00 00 00   // 814185724
FC 7C 87 30   // 814185728
00 7D 87 30   // 814185732
04 7D 87 30   // 16
```

New line of the table

```
10 00 00 00   // 84
54 00 00 00   // 70185301
55 F1 2E 04   // 20070306
A2 3F 32 01   // 15491037
DD 5F EC 00   // 20070306
A2 3F 32 01   // 15534889
29 0B ED 00   // 18
12 00 00 00   // 1
01 00 00 00   // 4486656
00 76 44 00   // 492
EC 01 00 00   // 1
01 00 00 00   // 814185724
FC 7C 87 30   // 814185728
00 7D 87 30   // 814185732
04 7D 87 30   // 16
```

And so on.....

My questions are:

1)Can you understand starting from this piece of converted data how the raw file is encoded??

2)How can I convert this raw file in order to create an excel or csv document with this data ordered by line?

This is my attempt in Java:

```
File fileInputString = new File(inputFileField.getText()); //Get the file in SWING 
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileInputString);  
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileDirectoryFolder.getText() +"/"+ fileInputString.getName()); //Create the new converted file 

byte[] fileContent = new byte[(int)fileInputString.length()]; // import the raw data length
fin.read(fileContent); // read the data

for(int i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++){
   out.write(fileContent[i]); // write the data
}
out.close();
```

Thank you

Comment: Excel has a very complicated file spec. If this software is not aimed at consumers, have you considered writing to a CSV file instead (comma separated values)? It can be opened in MS Excel and all other decent spreadsheet programs, too.

Comment: Definitely YES, I am interested in the data not in the format. CSV is absolutely fine